Want to reverse colors in gradient in choroplethr map
I have a graph working in 'choroplethr' but I would like to reverse the colors of the gradient.
Currently the low is "red" and the high is "blue". I have a situation where a low is a good thing and a high is a bad thing, so I would like the high to be "red".
Data:
df1 <- structure(list(region = c(6001L, 6003L, 6005L, 6007L, 6009L, 
6011L, 6013L, 6015L, 6017L, 6019L, 6021L, 6023L, 6025L, 6027L, 
6029L, 6031L, 6033L, 6035L, 6037L, 6039L, 6041L, 6043L, 6045L, 
6047L, 6049L, 6051L, 6053L, 6055L, 6057L, 6059L, 6061L, 6063L, 
6065L, 6067L, 6069L, 6071L, 6073L, 6075L, 6077L, 6079L, 6081L, 
6083L, 6085L, 6087L, 6089L, 6091L, 6093L, 6095L, 6097L, 6099L, 
6101L, 6103L, 6105L, 6107L, 6109L, 6111L, 6113L, 6115L), value = c(1.6, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 1.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 1.4, 
0.2, 0.3, 0, 11.8, 0.2, -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0.5, 0, 0, -0.1, 0.2, 
-0.2, -5, -0.3, 0.1, -1.9, 0.5, -0.1, -2.1, -2.5, -1, -0.5, -0.4, 
0, 0.1, -1.8, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.6, -0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, -0.8, 0.1, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-58L))

Code:
library(choroplethr)

county_choropleth(df1,
                  legend="Percent\nOver\nExpected\nBased On\nPopulation",
                  num_colors = 0,
                  state_zoom=c("california"))

Again, I would like the gradient to start with low/negative numbers being blue, and higher positive values being red.
I have been trying to change the colors using RColorBrewer and 'scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")' among other things, but nothing I have tried so far has worked.

Plot the negative of your data should work.

You mention that you tried to change the colors various ways. It would help if you included the code you tried that didn't work. This makes it hard for me to know whether your problem was with RColorBrewer or how to apply a custom scale to choroplethr. In my answer I show how to use the scale from the accepted answer while still using choroplethr to generate the map.

While choroplethr et al. are extremely useful tools for automating the mapping process, it is often difficult (or not possible) to achieve the custom results you want. I am not implying that there isn't a way to achieve what you want using choroplethr alone, but I generally find it easier to stick to using ggplot2.
With that in mind, here is an alternative that uses data downloaded using the tigris package. This will load an sf object into R that you can then dplyr::left_join() your df1 object to. As the FIPS values are strings in the tigris data (GEOID), they will first be converted to integers so they match your region values.
Then you can easily apply any ggplot functions to your data. For instance, I have chosen theme_void() as it is the option that most closely resembles the output from your code.
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- structure(list(region = c(6001L, 6003L, 6005L, 6007L, 6009L, 
6011L, 6013L, 6015L, 6017L, 6019L, 6021L, 6023L, 6025L, 6027L, 
6029L, 6031L, 6033L, 6035L, 6037L, 6039L, 6041L, 6043L, 6045L, 
6047L, 6049L, 6051L, 6053L, 6055L, 6057L, 6059L, 6061L, 6063L, 
6065L, 6067L, 6069L, 6071L, 6073L, 6075L, 6077L, 6079L, 6081L, 
6083L, 6085L, 6087L, 6089L, 6091L, 6093L, 6095L, 6097L, 6099L, 
6101L, 6103L, 6105L, 6107L, 6109L, 6111L, 6113L, 6115L), value = c(1.6, 
0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 1.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 1.4, 
0.2, 0.3, 0, 11.8, 0.2, -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0.5, 0, 0, -0.1, 0.2, 
-0.2, -5, -0.3, 0.1, -1.9, 0.5, -0.1, -2.1, -2.5, -1, -0.5, -0.4, 
0, 0.1, -1.8, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.6, -0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, -0.8, 0.1, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-58L))

# Load counties, join df1 data to counties sf
california_counties <- counties(state = "CA", cb = TRUE, year = 2023) |>
  mutate(GEOID = as.integer(GEOID)) |>
  left_join(df1, by = c("GEOID" = "region"))
# Using FIPS code '06' for state 'CA'

# Create state outline
california <- california_counties |>
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry))

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = california_counties,
          aes(fill = value),
          colour = "grey50") +
  geom_sf(data = california, colour = "black", fill = NA) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Percent\nOver\nExpected\nBased On\nPopulation",
                       low = "blue",
                       mid = "white",
                       high = "firebrick",
                       midpoint = 0) +
  theme_void()



Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for pointing out the 'tigris' package, that will definitely help me leverage my knowledge of 'ggplot2'.

The key is to realize what choroplethr actually does and returns.
As the answer above shows, creating choropleth maps with ggplot2 involves many steps. Choroplethr does all those steps for you (as well as others, such as alerting you about duplicate or missing values), and returns a ggplot2 object.
library(choroplethr)

df1 <- structure(list(region = c(6001L, 6003L, 6005L, 6007L, 6009L, 
                                 6011L, 6013L, 6015L, 6017L, 6019L, 6021L, 6023L, 6025L, 6027L, 
                                 6029L, 6031L, 6033L, 6035L, 6037L, 6039L, 6041L, 6043L, 6045L, 
                                 6047L, 6049L, 6051L, 6053L, 6055L, 6057L, 6059L, 6061L, 6063L, 
                                 6065L, 6067L, 6069L, 6071L, 6073L, 6075L, 6077L, 6079L, 6081L, 
                                 6083L, 6085L, 6087L, 6089L, 6091L, 6093L, 6095L, 6097L, 6099L, 
                                 6101L, 6103L, 6105L, 6107L, 6109L, 6111L, 6113L, 6115L), value = c(1.6, 
                                                                                                    0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 1.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 1.4, 
                                                                                                    0.2, 0.3, 0, 11.8, 0.2, -0.2, 0, -0.1, 0.5, 0, 0, -0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                    -0.2, -5, -0.3, 0.1, -1.9, 0.5, -0.1, -2.1, -2.5, -1, -0.5, -0.4, 
                                                                                                    0, 0.1, -1.8, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.2, 0.6, -0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                                                    0.2, 0.2, -0.8, 0.1, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                    -58L))
choro = county_choropleth(df1,
                      legend="Percent\nOver\nExpected\nBased On\nPopulation",
                      num_colors = 0,
                      state_zoom=c("california"))
class(choro)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"

A nice feature of ggplot2 is that you can override existing features of a plot by using the + operator. This means that you can override the default scale choroplethr uses with the one from the previous answer like this:
library(ggplot2)

county_choropleth(df1,
                  legend="Percent\nOver\nExpected\nBased On\nPopulation",
                  num_colors = 0,
                  state_zoom=c("california")) + 
scale_fill_gradient2(name = "Percent\nOver\nExpected\nBased On\nPopulation",
                       low = "blue",
                       mid = "white",
                       high = "firebrick",
                       midpoint = 0)  

Modern versions of ggplot2 even give a helpful warning saying that you are overriding the scale, and that it is using the last scale provided. When I run that code, for example, I get this message on the console:

Scale for fill is already present.
Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.

IMHO I think you actually had two questions. The first was "How do I create the scale / legend I want for this map?" The second was "How do I get choroplethr to use that scale / legend?"

@Friede I'm not exactly sure how to answer that. I'm the author of choroplethr and this is how I recommend solving this problem. This issue has come up a lot over the years. "How to change the scale" is a common question, and IMHO this is best answer (understanding that choroplethr returns a ggplot2 object, and that you can use + to add a new scale). The accepted answer ignores that this problem can be solved while still using choroplethr. As I wrote at the end, it seemed like there were actually two questions here.

I would recommend to state "that choroplethr returns a ggplot2 object" in your first sentence.
